# ComboBox.MaxDopDownItems is not working when adding items using the Click event

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, onclick

I am populating the ComboBox items with a list using the Click event. When it is already populated the MaxDropDownItems is not working. Does anyone know how to fix this one?

Here's the code:

```
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    ComboBox cb;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       cb = new ComboBox();

        cb.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
        cb.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Popup;
        cb.FormattingEnabled = true;
        cb.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(94, 21);
        cb.MaxDropDownItems = 5;
        cb.Click +=new EventHandler(cb_Click);

        this.Controls.Add(cb);
    }

    private void cb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        foreach (string str in list)
        {
            cb.Items.Add(str);
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        list.Add("1");list.Add("2");list.Add("3");
        list.Add("4");list.Add("5");list.Add("6");
        list.Add("7");
    }
```

MaxDropDownItems is set to 5 so the combobox should atleast show 5 items only:
[image]

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to set the [ComboBox.IntegralHeight property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.integralheight.aspx) to `false` when you setup your control (it defaults to `true`). From MSDN:

> When this property is set to true, the
>   control automatically resizes to
>   ensure that an item is not partially
>   displayed. If you want to maintain the
>   original size of the ComboBox based on
>   the space requirements of your form,
>   set this property to false.

Add this line before you add the combobox to the `Controls` collection:

```
cb.IntegralHeight = false;
```

Comment: WOW! When IntegralHeight is true MaxDropDownItems does not seem to work at all. I don't see how there is a relationship. My combobox went from taking up the whole screen, to properly limiting to 8 items...? This must be a .NET bug... seen in .NET 4.8 VS 2022